# Jade - how to point to my scripts folder?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I used tree to make the tree but it is coming too big, so please i hope allow me to just represent here..

-Root

...Views/layout.jade

...Scripts/controllers/controller.js

...Public/libs/angular

In my `layout.jade` I am having the following:

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='/libs/angular/angular.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/app.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='../scripts/controllers/controllers.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='../scripts/services/services.js')       
script(type='text/javascript', src='/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js')
```

However, it does not seem to work for Scripts.  Can please help me?  I have things in the Scripts folder which I want to link.

Answer (score 0):

remove .. from src='../scripts to like src='/scripts and move files from Scripts to public/scripts